# Unlist list of dataframes keeping keeping dataframe names

Tags: r

I have 84 dataframes on my workspace. There was no way I could import them as a list since the files were in different folders and directories.

```
ls() #command gives the names of these 84 dataframes. e.g [1] pav_DJF_histo.csv
```

I get the contents of each dataframe using:

```
dat<-mget(ls())
```

# and then get the mean per column

```
lst4<-lapply(dat,function(x) apply(x[,-c(1)],2,mean))
```

QUESTION: How can I unlist lst4 such that the names of the dataframes are the same as those given by

```
 ls()?
```

Many thanks for your suggestions.

NB: I have 84 dataframes in the list with 84 different names but all dataframes have same dimensions.

Comment: What's the difference between `dat` and `lst1`? If you are using `dat` in `lapply`, the resulting list will have the same names as you asked.

Comment: BTW, you could import them as a list via `lapply(fileNames,read.csv)`

Comment: @Jthorpe I could import as a list for sure but i could not do so given my data selection procedure.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming you want a data frame of the column means, you can call `rbind` on all the column means and then add a column identifying the source of that row:

```
# Reproducible setup
iris1.csv <- iris
iris2.csv <- iris
names <- c("iris1.csv", "iris2.csv")
dat <- mget(names)
lst4 <- lapply(dat, function(x) apply(x[,-5], 2, mean))

# Build the new data frame
means <- as.data.frame(do.call(rbind, lst4))
means$source <- names(lst4)
means
#           Sepal.Length Sepal.Width Petal.Length Petal.Width       isv    source
# iris1.csv     5.843333    3.057333        3.758    1.199333 0.3333333 iris1.csv
# iris2.csv     5.843333    3.057333        3.758    1.199333 0.3333333 iris2.csv
```

Comment: @josiber thanks very much. Is it possible to split 'means' into two dataframes such that Sepal.Length Sepal.Width Petal.Length Petal.Width       isv    source
# iris1.csv     5.843333    3.057333        3.758    1.199333 0.3333333 iris1.csv  is dataframe one  and #           Sepal.Length Sepal.Width Petal.Length Petal.Width       isv    source # iris2.csv     5.843333    3.057333        3.758    1.199333 0.3333333 iris2.csv is dataframe two?

Comment: @josiber, I would like to have 2 files (iris1.csv   and  iris2.csv) in my workspace with colnames<-Sepal.Length Sepal.Width Petal.Length Petal.Width       isv

Comment: @AsongZilefac If you do `means <- lapply(lst4, as.data.frame)` you will get the desired effect.